# C malloc a pointer multiple times

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

If I have a pointer: `char ** tmp = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_SIZE)`,
after assigning values to each block, I have a new pointer `char ** ptr = tmp`.

1). Can I `tmp = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_SIZE)` malloc it again without `free` it?

2). Does the `ptr` still has the values and also `tmp` points to a new block of memory?

I have a function to free all used memory at the end, so don't worry about `free`.

Comment: simple answer 1=yes, 2=yes. more explanation: when you `malloc` first time a block of memory is allocated and `tmp` gets the pointer to that location. then you are storing the pointer to `ptr` (now both `tmp` and `ptr` has the pointer to same location). when you call the second `malloc` another block of memory is assigned and `tmp` gets the new pointer. but `ptr` still have the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `tmp` to `ptr` keeps a reference to the malloced memory area. So re-assigning tmp using a new call to `malloc` is not a problem. This will not loose reference to the malloced memory as `ptr` is an existing alias.

So

1. yes, you can do another malloc. (You could do anyway, but would loose reference to malloced memory)
2. Yes, `ptr` still references the malloced area

BTW, doing a free *at the end* could be rather pointless if this would refer to *at the end of the program*. So, I assume you mean, *at the end of the current algorithm*.

Anyway, you need to keep references to the allocated memory. Usually it is advisable to release such memory as soon as it is no longer used.

Comment: Yeah I understand, because I will use these reference in another function, after using it, memory will be freed instantly. Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 1):

> 1). Can I `tmp = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_SIZE)` malloc it again without free it?

Yes , you can again allocate memory again . But `tmp` will now point to a new allocated memory and to previously allocated memory .

> 2). Does the `ptr` still has the values and also `tmp` points to a new block of memory?

Now `tmp` will point to newly allocated memory but `ptr` refers to the previous memory location which was allocated .

So in this way you don't loose reference to any of the memory block and can be freed .

Answer (score 1):

malloc is used to allocate a memory block. It allocates a block of memory of provided size and return a pointer to the beginning of the block.

So the first time you write

```
char ** tmp = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_SIZE)
```

it allocates memory and return a pointer pointing to beginning of memory location to temp. Now when you assign tmp to ptr, ptr now points to the allocated memory along with tmp. Now again if you write `tmp = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_SIZE)` it will allocate a new memory and return a pointer to which tmp will be pointing to. But ptr still continues to point to the previously allocated memory. So the answer to both of your question is YES.

I hope I was able to explain the things correctly.

Comment: Good explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    tmp = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * argc);
    while (argv[i])
    {
        tmp[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
        i++;
    }
    if (argc > 3)
       printf("%s", argv[2])
    return(0)}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's questions. Also, code without an explanation is not very helpful.